# How to sort answers in Android app?

Tags: support, answers, android-app, sorting

I can sort questions (according to activity, votes or newest).

But how I can sort answers to a question in StackExchange Android app?

Comment: I don't think that it is currently possible to sort answers in the android app.

Comment: You can do it via the mobile site. One of the many things the mobile site does better than the Android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments @[user000001](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/828193/user000001) and @[IKavanagh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1552737/ikavanagh). Merging both the comments to an answer:

> It is currently not possible to sort answers in the android app.
>
> But
> you can sort answers while using the mobile site.